Is the multivariate function continuous?
Consider the following set: $x_1 \geqslant0, \cdots, x_N \geqslant 0, x_1+\cdots+x_N \leqslant 1$, denoted by $S$.
Define a function $S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

For all the points that are not extreme points of $S$, let
\begin{align}
f(\vec{x}) & =
\sum_{i=1}^N \left[\left(1-x_i\right)\frac{p_N}{p_N-A_i}+x_i\right]
\\ \mbox{where}\
A_i & =
p_{i-1}+\sum_{k=i+1}^N\frac{x_k}{1-x_i}\left(p_{N-k+i}-p_{i-1}\right)
\end{align}
in which $p$ is in $[0,1]$ are strictly increasing in the subscriptions.
Note for extreme points of $S$, that is $x_j=1$, $A_j$ is not well defined due to the zero denominator ($1-x_j=0$).

In this case, we define
$$
f(\vec{x})=1+\sum_{i \neq j}\frac{p_N}{p_N-A_i}
$$
( note that $x_i=0$ for all $i \neq j$ ). I guess $f(\vec{x})$ is continuous on whole $S$.
Do I have to use the multivariate version of
$\varepsilon-\delta$ to prove it ( I don't know how to apply it to this case ) ?. Or are there any more straightforward methods ?.



